# Excel Worksheet_SelectionChange event not firing at all? (on both Office 2013 & 2016)

Tags: excel, vba, security, shared-libraries, mouseevent

I've been having a heck of a time accomplishing what I thought would be an incredibly simple test. All I am trying to achieve is to pop up a `MsgBox` when a user selects a new cell or changes the contents of a cell.

I've been at this for about 6 hours and so far have zero success! I have identical behavior with Office 2016 (Windows 10) and with Office 2013 (Windows 7).

Here are my method(s):

1. Create a new macro-enabled workbook.
2. Record a new macro in the workbook. Stop the recording. Open VBA.
3. Open the code for "Module 1" and replace the undesired code with the code below. Save the file.
4. File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Macro Settings -> "Trust access to the VBA project object model" is selected. Save the file.
5. I also have ensured `Application.EnableEvents = True`
6. I am expecting to be able to click on various cells, or edit cells, and received a `MsgBox` whenever the event occurs.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)       
    MsgBox "changed!"  
End

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "selected!"
End Sub

Public Sub Just_In_Case()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

What am I missing? Is there a security setting preventing this action event? I have the same behavior online at work as I do offline at home.

Thank you in advance for your help!  :)

PS Here is the screenshot of my VBA environment, if relevant: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXkMK.png

Comment: So you want that if user selects Sheet 2 (for example) then a popup should appear to notify that user has selected a different sheet ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `Workbook_SheetChange` code needs to be in the `ThisWorkbook` code module, not in a regular module.

EDIT: and the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` goes in the Worksheet code module

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/events.aspx

Comment: Thank you! That solved most of it! And the worksheet event goes in the `ThisWorksheet` code module.  :D

Comment: Yes - sorry I missed you were also using a worksheet-level event

Answer (score 0):

For complete reference, the solution is that my code was incorrectly placed in the `Module1` coding area. (I had no idea code could go anywhere else!)

`Workbook_SheetChange()` belongs under `ThisWorkbook`

`Worksheet_SelectionChange()` belongs under `Sheet1`

Like this! Image screenshots:
[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LCee.jpg)
[ThisWorkbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjJjv.jpg)

Thank you so much, Tim, for your help!  :D